# delete core data entry doesn't work

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

I try to delete an core data entry using Swift. I also use the fetched results controller for loading the entries. This is my code:

```
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Person")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = '\(item)'")
    var error : NSError?

    if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error),
       let managedObject = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
       context.deleteObject(managedObject)
    }
```

I don't know why but if this code runs the entry is deleted out of the table but if i restart the app the table includes the task which i've deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only deletes the object from the managed object context (which is the scratchpad for making changes). To persist anything done in a managed object context to the underlying database you need to save it first:

```
 if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error),
       let managedObject = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
       context.deleteObject(managedObject)
    }

let saveError: NSError?
context.save(&saveError)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save.

**Swift 1.2**

```
context.save(nil)
```

**Swift 2**

```
do { try context.save() } catch {}
```